# Get-AzADUser under Azure Automation with Reader UMI: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I have an Azure Automation account with a PowerShell runbook that has:

```
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName '<me@mydomain.com>'
```

In addition, I have a user-assigned managed identity in the same subscription and resource group as the Automation account, which has a Reader role assignment at Resource Group scope.

This UMI is applied to the Automation account `(through <Automation account> | Identity -> User-assigned -> +Add).`

When I run the above runbook in the portal, I get an error on `Get-AzADUser`, details `*[Authorization_RequestDenied] : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.*` and job stream details:

```
*Az.MSGraph.internal\Get-AzADUser : 
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. At 
C:\Modules\Global\Az.Resources\MSGraph.Autorest\custom\Get- 
AzADUser.ps1:199 char:9 + Az.MSGraph.internal\Get-AzADUser 
@PSBoundParameters + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: ({ ConsistencyLe...= , Expand = }: 
<>f__AnonymousType5`7) [Get-AzADUser_List], Exception + 
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Authorization_RequestDenied,Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Cmdlets.GetAzADUser_List*
```

I don't have my head fully around the security/permissions model but I've done what seems sufficient, so I must be missing something.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an **Azure web app and enabled managed identity** like below:

[image]

To fetch the users from Azure Active Directory, make sure to assign **`Directory.Read.All`** API permission to managed identity.

Use the below **PowerShell script** to assign permission:

```bash
$TenantID="TenantID"
$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
$DisplayNameOfMSI="testruk" 
$PermissionName = "Directory.Read.All" 


Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantID 
$MSI = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$DisplayNameOfMSI'")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$GraphAppId'"
$AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | `
Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application"}
New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId `
-ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $AppRole.Id
```

[image]

The **API permission assigned successfully to the Service Principal** like below:

[image]

Now, I am able to fetch the user's successfully:

```bash
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName '<xxx@mydomain.com>'
```

[image]

Comment: That PowerShell got me there, thanks!  
  
The only thing I can't figure out is why this newly-created role assignment doesn't show up under `Get-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -All $True`.  Also, I can't find it under the automation account anywhere - there's no security -> permissions option (unlike your web app), and it doesn't appear under identity -> system-managed.  The module does reject attempts to add the role assignment again, so it's there... I just can't otherwise confirm.

Comment: Go to Enterprise Applications - Your managed identity - Permissions